# JavaScript asynchronous loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do an asynchronous loop in JavaScript? I've been using the following recursive method but I feel like there is probably a cleaner way. Any links / advice would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
var titles = ['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3'];
var i = 0;
addColumns();

function addColumns () {
    if (i < titles.length) {
        var data =  { 
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldText' },
            'FieldTypeKind': 3,
            'Title': titles[i],
            'MaxLength': '22' 
        };

        postToSP.createColumns(baseURL, listName, data)
            .then(function () {
                i++;
                addColumns();
            })
            .catch(function(e){
                console.log('Error: ' + e);
            })
    } else {
        return;
    };
};
```

Comment: Why do the calls need to execute in sequence? Is order that important?

Comment: They don't need to be in sequence, but ShrePoint throws an error when trying to write all 3 concurrently

Comment: Ah ok. Then definitely use the first pattern in my answer as the next call won't be fired off until the previous one round-trips. Second tries to do them all concurrently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the executions are value-independent (i.e. one does not depend on the value of the previous one) but sequential (they have to be round-trip completed in a deterministic order):

```
var allDone = titles.reduce((prev, title) => {
  var data =  { 
    '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldText' },
    'FieldTypeKind': 3,
    'Title': title,
    'MaxLength': '22' 
  };
  return prev.then(_ => postToSP.createColumns(baseURL, listName, data));
}, Promise.resolve(true));
```

This will queue up a series of ajax requests that will only kick off once the previous one completes. Error handling is left as an exercise to the reader. If the calls *don't* necessarily have to complete in a certain order, it's much cleaner this way:

```
let allDone = Promise.all(titles.map(title => postToSP.createColumns...));
```

Either way, now you've got a single Promise that will resolve when all the async calls complete.

Answer (score 0):

ES2017: You can wrap async code inside a function(say XHRPost) returning a promise( Async code inside the promise).

Then call the function(XHRPost) inside the for loop but with the magical Await keyword. :)

```js
let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
let url = 'http://sumersin/forum.social.json';

function XHRpost(i) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        let params = 'id=nobot&%3Aoperation=social%3AcreateForumPost&subject=Demo1' + i + '&message=Here%20is%20the%20Demo&_charset_=UTF-8';
        http.open('POST', url, true);
        http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
                console.log("Done " + i + "<<<<>>>>>" + http.readyState);
                if(http.readyState == 4){
                    console.log('SUCCESS :',i);
                    resolve();
                }
        }
        http.send(params);       
   });
}

for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    await XHRpost(i);
   }
```